# How to fill vertical space in nested Column in ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the green box to fill the vertical space so `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` will work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(_app);

const title = "Layout test";

var _app = new MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: const Text(title),
    ),
    body: new _LayoutTest(),
  ),
);

class _LayoutTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return new ListView(
      children: [
        new Container(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          child: new Row(
            children: [
              new Image.network(
                // this can be any image
                "http://via.placeholder.com/185x278",
                width: size.width / 5,
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  // this should fill vertical space
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [
                      const Text("Top"),
                      const Text("Bottom"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can give the inner Container same height as outer container:

```
class _LayoutTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final newRandom = new Random().nextInt(50);

    return new ListView(
      children: [
        new Container(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          child: new Row(
            children: [
              new Container(
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                width: size.width / 5,
                height: 200.0 + newRandom,
              ),
              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [
                      const Text("Top"),
                      const Text("Bottom"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  height: 200.0 + newRandom,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. But I was a bit unclear. The "random" is just a placeholder for unknown height (e.g. an image). So that doesn't solve it for me :(

Comment: Your can give that image a fix height then.

Comment: Its not known at build time

Comment: My question is now updated with a network image instead.

Comment: Even if it is a network image you can give it a fix height. It will also look good if all widgets in the list will have a uniform height.

Comment: In this case i can't. Images have different ratio. The important thing is the width.